# Proof of a property of Greatest Integer Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $a,b,q\in\mathbb{Z}^+, r\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a=qb+r,0\leq r\lt b,$ how do you prove that $q=\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor$ and $r=a-b\lfloor\frac{a}{b}\rfloor$?

Comment: You are supposed to post some thoughts of your own, first, you know.

Comment: Um, how can it not?  $q = a/b - r/b $ so $q < a/b $.  Can you finish it.

Comment: Sorry!! New to the site!! Thanks for the suggestions @dxiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only need to prove $q=\lfloor\dfrac ab\rfloor$ as the other result follows immediately from $r=a-bq$.

We have $\dfrac ab=q+\dfrac rb$, and we know that $0\le\dfrac rb\lt1$ and that $q$ is an integer.

So $\lfloor\dfrac ab\rfloor=\lfloor q+\dfrac rb\rfloor=\lfloor q\rfloor=q$.